# XNA 4.0: first person camera movement on terrain jitter

Tags: xna, camera, collision-detection, terrain

Lately I've succeed in implementing first person camera and terrain collision but I've hit yet another wall which is camera jittering when moving across the height-map. While it's not so uncommon problem I couldn't find any clear solution nor direction I should follow to achieve desired effect. 
Can anyone suggest how could I adapt my implementation to make rendering perform smooth?

Camera class:

```
public class Camera
{
    public Matrix view { get; protected set; }
    public Matrix projection { get; protected set; }
    public Vector3 direction { get; protected set; }
    public Vector3 side_direction { get; protected set; }
    public Vector3 position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 up { get; protected set; }
    public float _rotationX { get; protected set; }
    public float _rotationY { get; protected set; }
    public float rotX
    {
        get { return _rotationX; }
        set
        {
            _rotationX = value;
            RotateX(value);
        }
    }
    public float rotY
    {
        get { return _rotationY; }
        set
        {
            _rotationY = value;
            RotateY(value);
        }
    }
    public Matrix rotationX;
    public Matrix rotationY;
    public Camera(Game game, Vector3 pos, Vector3 up)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.direction = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        this.side_direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
        this.rotationX = Matrix.Identity;
        this.rotationY = Matrix.Identity;
        this.position = pos;
        this.up = up;
        this.view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(pos, pos + direction, up);
        this.projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                     MathHelper.PiOver4, (float)Game.Window.ClientBounds.Width /
                     (float)Game.Window.ClientBounds.Height,
                     1, 3000);
    }
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    public void RotateX (float degree)
    {
        if (_rotationX + degree >= 89)
            _rotationX = 89;
        else if (_rotationX + degree <= -89)
            _rotationX = -89;
        else
            _rotationX = _rotationX + degree;
        float radians = MathHelper.ToRadians(_rotationX);
        rotationX = Matrix.CreateRotationX(radians);
        updateView();
    }
    public void RotateY (float degree)
    {
        _rotationY = (_rotationY + degree) % 360;
        float radians = MathHelper.ToRadians(_rotationY);
        rotationY = Matrix.CreateRotationY(radians);
        updateView();
    }
    protected void updateView()
    {
        this.side_direction = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1, 0, 1), rotationX);
        this.direction = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), rotationX);
        this.side_direction = Vector3.Transform(side_direction, rotationY);
        this.direction = Vector3.Transform(direction, rotationY);
        this.view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, position + direction, up);
    }
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public void moveForward(float p)
    {
        this.position = position + direction * p;
        updateView();
    }
    public void moveSide(float p)
    {
        this.position = position + side_direction * p;
        updateView();
    }
    public void moveForward(float p, Terrain t)
    {
        Vector3 tmp = position + direction * p;
        tmp.Y = t.GetTerrainHeight(tmp.X, tmp.Z);
        this.position = tmp;
        updateView();
    }
    public void moveSide(float p, Terrain t)
    {
        Vector3 tmp = position + side_direction * p;
        tmp.Y = t.GetTerrainHeight(tmp.X, tmp.Z);
        this.position = tmp; 
        updateView();
    }
    public void Draw(ref BasicEffect effect)
    {
        effect.Projection = this.projection;
        effect.View = this.view;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What is it that the camera is following when it jitters? Have you considered [smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) the movement?

Comment: Camera is following a single point which is camera position vector (Camera.position), view matrix is calculated from Camera.position and Camera.direction normal, the rest is under moveForward(float, Terrain) function. I don't think smoothing would help given that camera is being updated 60 times a second (yes, fps is fine)

Comment: Have you tried it? More frequent updates may just mean you need stronger smoothing (i.e. considering more values to smooth over).

Comment: I didn't, which technique/filter should I try out first?

Comment: A simple method would be to keep a store of the last `n` points the camera was calculated to be positioned at and set the *actual* visible position of the camera to an average of those points. (Tweak `n` as necessary.) This "running average" changes more smoothly than the raw data.

Comment: I've tried it but my terrain is kinda bumpy so it's very easy to go under textures while climbing or floating in the air while descending, in fact there is no jittering but it's far from calling that an ultimate solution. Found this sample [link](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/collision_3d_heightmap_normals), how is following a dynamic mesh different from following a point, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you say us more about GetTerrainHeight function?
As far as I can read, you are reading terrain height directly - is it stored in an array or something?
Try to interpolate terrain height between adjacent points as your character position can easily be between two or more data points (if I understood your code right).

**UPD:**
Try to lerp between current camera position and calculated camera position instead of immediately assigning it:
`this.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.position, tmp, 0.05f);`
0.05f is the threshold by what percent (in range from 0.0f to 1.0f) you want to move towards target. Calibrate it or even introduce GameTime to make smoothing independent from your framerate.

Comment: it's the same function as [this one](http://www.riemers.net/Forum/index.php?var=663&var2=0)

Comment: @thormond Are you using the function from the first post or the simplified one?